# Approach for physics with parallax endless scrolling

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I know ways to set a world in the main screen , and put bodies into it , and manage a whole game with contacts and etc . (box2d ,cocos2d)

I also know how to `CCFolow` a sprite/body and move the layer with him , or set a parallax background to show backgrounds layers moving right .

BUT , i am wondering what is the right approach to endless scroller with bodies that are coming all the time .

1. I  need to define an endless world bounds? is it possible ?
2. how can i dynamically add bodies to the parallax strip all the time and **move** them with him ?
3. I can see in some games a whole structures like roads,hills , that are coming endlessly , and i am sure they didnt create ALL of them for 1000's pixels length , so how do they create them -in a simple way (i am sure you dont draw vectors all over the road to define bodies for kilometers .. but can set them in some random simple way, )
4. is there a visual tool to create visually all of these or just by coding box2d ?

Comment: Why closing such an important questions ?

Comment: i agree it's important but it's also very broad and you're asking many different questions at once. You mention games but none specifically (tiny wings?). The editor question is a case for google, you'll quickly find rube, physicseditor and box2d-editor or whatever it's called.